# Stripe proceeding payment error 500 (internal server error)

Tags: stripe-payments

So as the title says, I have a problem proceeding the order, I just get this error:

```
GET https://website.com/public/intent 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

That's how I implemented stripe:

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<script>
 // Stripe stuff
 var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_key');
 var elements = stripe.elements();</script>
```

Into logs I get this error:

```
"This API call cannot be made with a publishable API key. Please use a secret API key. You can find a list of your API keys at https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys."
```

When I'm trying to use the secret key it tells me to use the public key and vice versa.

Can someone help me out ?

Comment: Please share more details. When an error 500 occurs, there's usually something written to either your server's or your application's log

Comment: I get this error: "This API call cannot be made with a publishable API key. Please use a secret API key. You can find a list of your API keys at https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys."

Answer (score 1):

What API calls are you trying to make? Integrating with Stripe, for example following [this guide to accept a payment](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&lang=node&client=html&ui=elements), requires **both** client-side *and* server-side components. In the JavaScript world you'd use `stripe-node` ([github](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node)) on your server with your secret key to [create a Payment Intent](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements#web-create-payment-intent), and use Stripe.js with a publishable key in your client application (eg: React app) to [collect payment details](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements#web-collect-card-details) and [submit the payment](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements#web-submit-payment).

**Never** include your secret key in a client-side application. This is not secure.